# How do I construct a CASE expression in SQL applying a for a simple estimation for the future?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I am developing a materialized view in which I want create a CASE expression for a query.

I have the CASE expression complete for the past results (2022,2021,2020,2019). But not for 2023 as I don't have the full data for 2023.

How do I construct a CASE expression applying factor like 1.5 and multiplying by the previous_year to get a simple prediction. `1.5 * 335.84 = 503.76` is the value in 2023?

See https://dbfiddle.uk/Kj9xrD1c for the 'results' table as what I want or the following

```
select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM item_.transaction_date) AS year,
    sum(case when EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)>EXTRACT(YEAR FROM item_.transaction_date) 
        then item_.cost 
        else 0 end) 
            as box
from item_
    GROUP BY year;
```

```
| year   |   box  |
| -----  | -----  |
| 2019   | 189.13 |
| 2020   | 104.70 |
| 2021   | 228.40 |
| 2022   | 335.84 |
| 2023   | 0 |
```

I added this OVER function to the CASE ELSE statement
OVER (PARTITION by EXTRACT(YEAR FROM item_.transaction_date) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) but that still isn't right

This is what I want:

```
| year   | box |
| -----  | ----- |
| 2019   | 189.13 |
| 2020   | 104.70 |
| 2021   | 228.40 |
| 2022   | 335.84 |
| 2023   | 503.76 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more flexible approach is to use currentdate to determine the current year and use that to get the the last years revenue with an additional 50%, while i think that would be very optimistic

```
    select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM item_.transaction_date) AS year,
        CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM item_.transaction_date) < date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) 
       THEN sum( item_.cost  ) 
      ELSE (SELECT sum( item_.cost) FROM item_ WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM item_.transaction_date) = date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 year') 
      ) * 1.5
      END
                as box
    from item_
        GROUP BY year
      Order by year;
```

| year | box |
| --- | --- |
| 2019 | 189.13 |
| 2020 | 104.70 |
| 2021 | 228.40 |
| 2022 | 335.84 |
| 2023 | 503.760 |

> ```
> SELECT 5
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X2aN6Mt6)