# How do I construct a CASE expression in SQL applying a for a simple estimation for the future with conditions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I modify the following CASE expression with condition such as type = 'A' and create a 2023 estimation with a general factor of 1.5 ?

Please see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_Fv8pz4S) for reference.
My data table is below :

```
|id |transaction_date   |cost   |type|
|1  |2019-01-01         |94.12  |A   |
|2  |2019-02-15         |95.01  |A   |
|5  |2020-03-01         |36.22  |A   |
|3  |2020-05-16         |45.22  |B   |
|4  |2020-06-10         |10.84  |A   |
|6  |2020-12-09         |12.42  |A   |
|8  |2021-02-28         |72.44  |B   |
|9  |2021-04-16         |91.08  |A   |
|7  |2021-05-16         |64.88  |A   |
|12 |2022-01-22         |55.87  |B   |
|13 |2022-04-06         |99.66  |A   |
|10 |2022-06-09         |53.34  |A   |
|11 |2022-10-05         |36.93  |A   |
|14 |2022-11-18         |90.04  |A   |
|15 |2023-01-23         |82.30  |A   |
```

This SQL query does specify type = 'A' and sums 'A' columns
but does not contain the 2023 estimation.

```
select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM item_.transaction_date) AS year,
    sum(case when EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)>EXTRACT(YEAR FROM item_.transaction_date) AND type = 'A' 
        then item_.cost 
        else 0 end) 
            as box_A
from item_
    GROUP BY year
    order by year;
```

```
|year|  box_a |
|2019|  189.13|
|2020|  59.48 |
|2021|  155.96|
|2022|  279.97|
|2023|  0     |
```

This following SQL query does contain the 2023 estimation but without conditions so the type = 'A' is not specified so the the * in box_a contains the the wrong values.

```
  select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM item_.transaction_date) AS year,
    CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM item_.transaction_date) < date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)
   THEN sum( item_.cost  ) 
  ELSE (SELECT sum( item_.cost) FROM item_ WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM item_.transaction_date) = date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 year') 
  ) * 1.5
  END
            as box_a
from item_
    GROUP BY year
  Order by year;
```

```
|year|  box_a   |
|2019|  189.13  |
|2020|  *104.70*|
|2021|  *228.40*|
|2022|  *335.84*|
|2023|  *503.76*|
```

This is what I would like

```
|year|  box_a |
|2019|  189.13|
|2020|  59.48 |
|2021|  155.96|
|2022|  279.97|
|2023|  419.96|     |
```

This [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75562006/how-do-i-construct-a-case-expression-in-sql-applying-a-for-a-simple-estimation-f/75562134#75562134) was good to use in reference to WITHOUT conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LAG()`. For example:

```
select 
  year,
  case when box_a = 0 then lag(box_a) over(order by year) * 1.5
       else box_a 
  end as box_a
from ( -- original query here
  select
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM item_.transaction_date) AS year,
    sum(case when EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) >
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM item_.transaction_date) AND type = 'A' 
        then item_.cost 
        else 0 end
    ) as box_A
  from item_
  GROUP BY year
) x
order by year
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1XlkJlZl).

**Note**: As a general rule I personally prefer to use null to represent the absence of data, rather than the value zero, that theoretically could be a valid amount.

Comment: The conditional sum could also be written as `sum(item_.cost) filter (where ...)` I personally find that easier to read

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Absolutely agree.